# Is it possible to Manage .htacess file from Admin Panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, htaccess

Is there any way I can edit and update `.htaccess` file from **admin panel** of Magento. I'm using **Magento 1.9**

Answer (score 2):

**.htaccess** is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software, so That's not possible to edit from admin....

you can check below links for more information  :

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170819/what-is-htaccess-file

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with core Magento functionality but it is possible if you install a third-party module like [Creare SEO](https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/news/creare-seo-magento-extension) (it's free). That said, I'm not sure of support for Magento 1.9